# Need help determining whether this question is Bernoulli or not.

Tags: solution-verification, expected-value

On a certain highway, 7% of the vehicles
have $18$ wheels, and the other 93% of the vehicles have $4$ wheels. (We ignore
motorcycles, etc., for simplicity.) A child looks out the window and counts the
wheels on the next vehicle to pass.

a. What is the expected number of wheels?

My work:

I'm not sure which interpretation is correct and would like it if someone could tell me which one is.

$E(X)$ where $X$ is the random variable that represents the number of wheels is $E(X) = 4 \cdot 0.93 + 18 \cdot 0.07 = 4.98$ wheels. Is this the correct interpretation? OR is  $E(X) = p = 0.07$ where $p$ is the probability of a "success" (the kid sees a $18$-wheeler) the correct interpretation?

Thank You!

Comment: It's the first one.  It's the average number of wheels.  It can't possibly be the result of the second calculation, which doesn't use the number of wheels on either class of vehicle.

Comment: I see thank you for your help!